# K8s. problem with pods and ssh connection

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, kubernetes-pod

Lately I have problem with `Pods` in *k8s*.
I have 5 masters and 5 worker nodes, where I have 19 `Pods`.
If I make, for example: `ssh sonar.***.ru` from worker - all is OK,
but if this command is run from `Pod`, it fails, because of time out or a lot of time find connect. or it takes a lot of time to connect.

I have **flannel**, **docker**, **kubelet** and **kube-proxy**, **kubernetes** is `1.13`.
What other information can I provide to get help in resolving the issue ?
It started about 2 weeks ago.

#### update:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 

nameserver 192.168.0.10
search bamboo-agents-prod.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local raiffeisen.ru
options ndots:5 

$ nslookup sonar.raiffeisen.ru

Server: 10.243.4.15
Address: 10.243.4.15#53
Name: sonar.raiffeisen.ru
Address: 10.243.90.81
```

The error I get why trying to ssh:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname sonar.raiffeisen.ru: Name or service not known
```

I cannot connect to it at all and also cannot connect to any other host from all my `Pods`, not only one! `ping` is working, but for first package I also wait some time.

Comment: Could you run `kubectl exec pod-name cat /etc/resolv.conf` ? And `kubectl exec pod-name nslookup sonar.***.ru` ?

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 192.168.0.10
search bamboo-agents-prod.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local raiffeisen.ru
options ndots:5

nslookup sonar.raiffeisen.ru

Server:         10.243.4.15
Address:        10.243.4.15#53

Name:   sonar.raiffeisen.ru
Address: 10.243.90.81

Comment: What is the exact error when ssh connection attempt fails ? Are you getting any message from ssh server or you cannot connect to it at all ? Are you able to ping it ?  Are you able to `ssh` to any other host from this `Pod` ?

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname sonar.raiffeisen.ru: Name or service not known   I cannot connect to it at all and also cannot connect to any other host from all my pods, not only one! Ping is work, but first package I also wait some time.

Comment: One piece of advice: try to add new information related to the question, such as logs, command output, etc. by editing the question itself rather than in the comments. It's much more readable for others, so it can increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: I already edited your question. Please simply accept the edit request. I have one more question. It looks like `nslookup` run from `Pod` returns IP address of `sonar.raiffeisen.ru` which in your environment happens to be `10.243.90.81`. Can you `ssh` using this IP ?